# Sacar el nombre en lugar del ID

Tags: php, javascript, phpmyadmin

tengo una lista de datos obtenidos de una base de datos, pero cuando le doy a "eliminar", en el texto me sale si quiero eliminar el producto "id", y queria cambiar que en lugar del ID, salga el nombre del producto. 
El código que tengo puesto es este:

```
<form autocomplete="on" method="post" name="delete_accesori" id="delete_accesori" action="index.php?page=controller_accesori&op=delete&id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
    <table border='0'>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"  colspan="2"><h3>¿Desea seguro borrar el producto <?php echo $_GET['id'] ; ?>?</h3></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><button type="submit" class="Button_green"name="delete" id="delete">Aceptar</button></td>
            <td align="center"><a class="Button_red" href="index.php?page=controller_accesori&op=list">Cancelar</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

y si en lugar de poner $_GET['id'], pongo $_GET['accesori'] no me sale ese campo... 
Alguna sugerencia? Gracias de antemano!!

EDITADO:
A petición del usuario "Marcos" añado el codigo donde se imprime la información del producto:

```
<h1>Informació del producte</h1>
<p>
<table border='2'>
    <tr>
        <td>Accesori: </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                echo $accesori['accesori'];
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>Imatge de l'accesori: </td>
            <td>
               <img src=" <?php
                    echo $accesori['imatge_accesori'];
                ?> ">
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email: </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                echo $accesori['email'];
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Còdic del producte: </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                echo $accesori['codprod'];
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Marca: </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                echo $accesori['marca'];
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Modelo: </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                echo $accesori['modelo'];
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Cantitat: </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                echo $accesori['cantitat'];
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Fecha de stock: </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                echo $accesori['data1'];
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Fecha d'inici de l'oferta: </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                echo $accesori['data2'];
            ?>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Pais: </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                echo $accesori['pais'];
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Idioma: </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                echo $accesori['idioma'];
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Observaciones: </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                echo $accesori['observaciones'];
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Valoració: </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                echo $accesori['valoracio'];
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</p>
<p><a href="index.php?page=controller_accesori&op=list">Volver</a></p>
```

También quiero comentar que ya he probado a realizar lo de  `<?php echo accesori['accesori'];?>` en el delete para que salga el nombre del accesorio, pero no funciona.

EDITO:

La función para eliminar el accesorio es esta:

```
    function delete_accesori($accesori){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM producte WHERE id='$accesori'";
    /*  print_r($sql);
        die();*/
        $conexion = connect::con();
        $res = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
        connect::close($conexion);
        return $res;
    }
```

La función para insertar productos en la base de datos es esta:

```
    function insert_accesori($datos){

        $id=$datos[id];
        $accesori=$datos[accesori];
        $imatge_accesori=$datos[imatge_accesori];
        $email=$datos[email];
        $codprod=$datos[codprod];
        $marca=$datos[marca];
        $modelo=$datos[modelo];
        $cantitat=$datos[cantitat];
    //  $valoracio=$datos[valoracio];
        $data1=$datos[data1];
        $data2=$datos[data2];
        $pais=$datos[pais];
        foreach ($datos[idioma] as $indice) {
            $idioma=$idioma."$indice/"; 
        }
        $observaciones=$datos[observaciones];
        foreach ($datos[valoracio] as $indice) {
            $valoracio=$valoracio."$indice/";
        }
        $conexion = connect::con();
        $compro_cod = "SELECT * FROM producte WHERE codprod = '$codprod'";
        $existe = mysqli_query($conexion,$compro_cod);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($existe) > 0){

             print_r('Error: Ya existe ese codigo <br/> <a href="index.php?page=controller_accesori&op=list">Volver</a>');

             die();
        } else{
            $sql = " INSERT INTO producte (id, accesori, imatge_accesori, email, codprod, marca, modelo, cantitat, data1, data2, pais, idioma, observaciones, valoracio)"
                . " VALUES ('$id','$accesori', '$imatge_accesori', '$email', '$codprod', '$marca', '$modelo', '$cantitat', '$data1', '$data2', '$pais', '$idioma', '$observaciones', '$valoracio')";

            $res = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
            connect::close($conexion);
            return $res;
        }
    }
```

En ese código también compruebo que el código del producto no se pueda repetir.

Esta es la parte del código te que lleva a la opción de borrar el producto:

```
   case 'delete';
        if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
            try{
                $daoaccesori = new DAOAccesori();
                $rdo = $daoaccesori->delete_accesori($_GET['id']);
            }catch (Exception $e){
                $callback = 'index.php?page=503';
                die('<script>window.location.href="'.$callback .'";</script>');
            }

            if($rdo){
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Borrado en la base de datos correctamente")</script>';
                $callback = 'index.php?page=controller_accesori&op=list';
                die('<script>window.location.href="'.$callback .'";</script>');
            }else{
                $callback = 'index.php?page=503';
                die('<script>window.location.href="'.$callback .'";</script>');
            }
        }

        include("module/accesori/view/delete_accesori.php");
        break;
```

Comment: A simple vista el problema es que el nombre no viene por `GET`, sino que esta en otra variable. ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el código donde imprimes la info del producto?

Comment: He añadido la información que me pides.

Comment: Si en el `form` al reemplazar `$_GET['id']` por `$accesori['accesori']` no te funciona, entonces es necesario que muestres y/o expliques el orden en cada se carga los elementos en la página. O mejor aún, agrega el código completo

Comment: Deberás hacer una búsqueda en la base de datos por la `id` para obtener el nombre del artículo o bien enviarlo desde la página en la que enviaste la petición de borrado. He visto que en ningún sitio de tu código aparece el enlace que te lleva al borrado del artículo. ¿Podrías incluirlo? Gracias.

Comment: acabo de realizar las introducciones en la pregunta las cosas que me sugeris ambos

Comment: Habría sido suficiente que expliques brevemente la lógica de tu programa y de dónde sacas la información, de lo contrario hay que leer todo el contenido de tu pregunta tratando de adivinar dicha lógica. Parece que tú haces una llamada a la eliminación desde aquí: `$rdo = $daoaccesori->delete_accesori($_GET['id']);`  ¿cierto? La cuestión es: ¿de dónde sacas ese `$_GET['id']`? Si al eliminar quieres mostrar el nombre del producto en vez del `id` entonces de donde mismo sacas el `id` tendrás que sacar el `nombre` y pasárselo también a la función `delete_accesori` junto con el `id`.

Comment: En donde lo mandas a eliminar? Alli en vez de mandar por $_GET el Id, le mandas el nombre, esto puede ser incluso con javascript

Comment: Una pregunta: que aún no hemos confirmado: Realmente tienes claro que en la base de datos, los productos tienen el nombre informado? No podría ser que estén vacíos por cualquier otro motivo y estemos tomando como seguro que tienen algo escrito?

Comment: Si, en la base de datos todos los productos tienen todos los campos con datos

Comment: Lo que me he dado cuenta es que si en el controller, hago un print_r($_GET['accesori']); die();, no sale nada, a menos que he en $_GET ponga 'id'